# Getting "duplicate key value violates unique constraint" error when saving entities with Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

For my `Spring Boot` REST API I have an entity as follows:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ArchetypeMatchUp
{
    @Id
    @JsonIgnore
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = SEQUENCE, generator = "seq_archetype_match_up_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_archetype_match_up_generator", sequenceName = "seq_archetype_match_up")
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Archetype> firstPlayerArchetype;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, orphanRemoval = true)
    @OrderColumn
    private List<Archetype> secondPlayerArchetype;

    // ...
}
```

With this, I want to be able to represent arbitrary match-ups between archetypes. Both lists typically have 1 - 2 elements in them. The first archetypes list and second archetypes list may share the same archetype, e.g. `[A, B]` and `[B, C]` or `[A, C]` and `[C, B]`.

Next, the exception reproduction test case:

```
private void testDuplicateKeyBug()
{
    // Insert the archetypes
    var firstArchetype = Archetype.builder().name("1st Archetype").build();
    var secondArchetype = Archetype.builder().name("2nd Archetype").build();
    var thirdArchetype = Archetype.builder().name("3rd Archetype").build();
    firstArchetype = archetypeRepository.save(firstArchetype);
    secondArchetype = archetypeRepository.save(secondArchetype);
    thirdArchetype = archetypeRepository.save(thirdArchetype);

    // Insert the 1st archetype match-up
    val firstArchetypeMatchUp = ArchetypeMatchUp.builder()
            .firstPlayerArchetype(Arrays.asList(firstArchetype, secondArchetype))
            .secondPlayerArchetype(Arrays.asList(secondArchetype, thirdArchetype))
            .build();
    archetypeMatchUpRepository.save(firstArchetypeMatchUp);

    // Insert the 2nd archetype match-up
    val secondArchetypeMatchUp = ArchetypeMatchUp.builder()
            .firstPlayerArchetype(Arrays.asList(firstArchetype, thirdArchetype))
            .secondPlayerArchetype(Arrays.asList(thirdArchetype, secondArchetype))
            .build();
    archetypeMatchUpRepository.save(secondArchetypeMatchUp); // Here, the exception occurs
}
```

At the 2nd `.save()` statement, the following exception occurs:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint ["PUBLIC.UK_ECYK6EE7KR3CRQAR8TP6N9GSO_INDEX_2 ON PUBLIC.ARCHETYPE_MATCH_UP_FIRST_PLAYER_ARCHETYPE(FIRST_PLAYER_ARCHETYPE_ID NULLS FIRST) VALUES ( /* 1 */ CAST(1 AS BIGINT) )"; SQL statement:
insert into archetype_match_up_first_player_archetype (archetype_match_up_id, first_player_archetype_id) values (?, ?) [23505-214]]
```

I noticed that `Hibernate` apparently created 3 tables:
[image]

[image]

However, the `first_player_archetype_id` column is declared as unique in my database (wrong) but of course I want to be able to insert the same `archetype` id multiple times for different relations (correct).

How can I fix this issue by adjusting my entity declarations or so to make the test case run successfully?

Comment: When I read your Example correct, then an Archytype can be im multiple ArchetypeMatchUps in the firstPlayerArchetype-List. So its ManyToMany and not OneToMany

Comment: @Turo: Yes, I noticed that seemed to have been it before I checked your comment, thanks for the confirmation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was using my entity in a many-to-many context, hence swapping the annotation out to be `@ManyToMany` fixed the issue. Now I can insert and delete as expected.